# Huge exception traces in Doctrine

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I'm new to Doctrine and I'm not using caching due to server settings limitations.

Problem is that Even outside of Doctrine I am getting really huge exception traces for my custom exceptions( the browser cannot render it properly ). As I see traces are getting large because Doctrine stores bunch of configuration data directly attached to every single entity object.

Have anybody familiar with Doctrine experienced something similar?
Is it because of lacking caching?
Anybody knows good slotution?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's true that doctrine generates huge exception traces. I always write exceptions to a file. In that case you can easily read it using an editor or command line tool like tail, vi, etc, etc. ( I prefer tail -f at all times while developing)

My experience is that you don't need to look at the complete stacktrace but only at the x-top lines to see what triggers the exception.

**Some extra notes:**

Because you're talking about caching I asssume you have this problem on a production environment. If so, remember that the performance of Doctrine relies on caching and that it is bad practice to output exceptions to the browser in a production environment.

Comment: Thanks Rene, actually I got into caching because I was exemining different setups with Doctrine. Of course I won't ever put exceptions to browser screen in production environment, but really thanks for your concern!!!

Comment: @FöldesiZsolt, no problem. I'm glad it wasn't on production